# jquery last child border if..else

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HTML

```
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">1
    </div>
     <div class="cc">a
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">2
    </div>
     <div class="cc">b
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('red');
$('.bb').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
    if(!$('.cc:last').is(':hidden')){
        if($('.bb:last').hasClass('red')){
            $('.cc:last').addClass('red');
            $('.bb:last').removeClass('red');
        }
    }else{
    $('.bb:last').addClass('red');
  }
});
```

**[Online sample -Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8VqB/3/)**

When click box `2` the border should be removed from `bb` then assigned to 'cc', second click the border should go back to `bb` whenever I just cannot get it right. from  `else{$('.bb:last').addClass('red');}` is not working.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: The `else` clause is for the hidden check, not for the red class check. Since `bb` is never hidden, it never falls into that clause.

Comment: Thank you. yes, just realized. here is the new one, but still not working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/L8VqB/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is should solve the problem you are having.

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('red');
$('.bb').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
    if($('.bb:last').is(this)){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    }
});
```

Here is a link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjmeyers/BXHSJ/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause was paired with the wrong `if`. This works correctly:

```
$('.bb:last').addClass('red');
$('.bb').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.cc').fadeToggle();
    if (!$('.bb:last').is(':hidden')) {
        if ($('.bb:last').hasClass('red')) {
            $('.cc:last').addClass('red');
            $('.bb:last').removeClass('red');
        } else {
            $('.bb:last').addClass('red');
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/L8VqB/2/)

Comment: should be `if(!$('.cc:last').is(':hidden'))` I just realized. when click on the first one, the red border applied to the box 2, if it is not hidden

Comment: The problem is that `fadeToggle` is asynchronous. When you check whether `.cc:last` is hidden, it isn't yet -- it has just started fading out.

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of the state, or set a class on the `cc` div.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Don't really want extra class to be added :-)